# Remove suffix as well as prefix from path in bash

Tags: bash

I have filepaths of the form:

```
../healthy_data/F35_HC_532d.dat
```

I want to extract `F35_HC_532d` from this. I can remove prefix and suffix from this filename in bash as:

```
for i in ../healthy_data/*; do echo ${i#../healthy_data/}; done # REMOVES PREFIX

for i in ../healthy_data/*; do echo ${i%.dat}; done # REMOVES SUFFIX
```

How can I combine these so that in a single command I would be able to remove both and extract only the part that I want?

Comment: Do all files end with `.dat`?

Comment: @hek2mgl: Yes!!

Comment: Ok, check my answer then

Comment: Off-topic, but `zsh` allows this: `echo $i:t:r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `Awk`, it is pretty simple,

```
for i in ../healthy_data/*
do 
    stringNeeded=$(awk -F/ '{split($NF,temp,"."); print temp[1]}' <<<"$i")
    printf "%s\n" "$stringNeeded"
done
```

The `-F/` splits the input string on `/` character, and `$NF` represents the last field in the string in that case, `F35_HC_532d.dat`, now the `split()` function is called with the de-limiter `.` to extract the part before the `dot`.

The options/functions in the above `Awk` are `POSIX` compatible.

---

Also `bash` does not support nested parameter expansions, you need to modify in two fold steps something like below:-

```
tempString="${i#*/*/}"
echo "${tempString%.dat}"
```

In a single-loop,

```
for i in ../healthy_data/*; do tempString="${i#*/*/}"; echo "${tempString%.dat}" ; done
```

The two fold syntax here, `"${i#*/*/}"` part just stores the `F35_HC_532d.dat` into the variable `tempString` and in that variable we are removing the `.dat` part as `"${tempString%.dat}"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, my question is how can I combine the two commands in bash instead of using some other thing like Awk. Any ideas?

Comment: @Peaceful: As I said, it is just another way of achieving the same. Remember `Awk` is installed in almost major Linux/Unix platforms, so you can use it for such a trivial job.

Comment: Yes. But you have written `i%.dat` instead of `tempString%.dat`

Comment: @Peaceful: Peace :) modified it

Answer (score 5):

You can use BASH regex for this like this and print captured group #1:

```
for file in ../healthy_data/*; do
    [[ $file =~ .*/([_[:alnum:]]+)\.dat$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```

Comment: That's quick! Can you give me some reference to understand the meaning of what you wrote as an answer?

Comment: Sorry I had to step away due to some work. [Please check this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-regular-expressions) Another thing to keep in mind that using pure BASH feature is much more efficient here than calling an external utility like `sed/awk`

Comment: Yes. I had exactly this in mind. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AkshayHegde : Yes, it's a good approach. However, the question was about combining two specific things and not about using regex. The last part of the accepted answer exactly does that.

Comment: No, even accepted answer does it in 2 steps in last part because those 2 directives cannot be combined in single step in bash. Regex on only easy you can get in a single step using pure bash.

Comment: @anubhava: After learning this approach, I am actually using it over the one that I accepted initially. However, it seems too impolite now to change the accepted answer.

Comment: Agreed. I was just stating some technical fact, even I would not want grabbing a tick mark from my buddy @Inian

Answer (score 1):

If all files end with `.dat` (as you confirmed) you can use the `basename` command:

```
basename -s .dat /path/to/files/*
```

If there are *many(!)* of those files, use `find` to avoid an *argument list too long error*:

```
find /path/to/files -maxdepth 1 -name '*.dat' -exec basename -s .dat {} +
```

For a shell script which needs to deal if any number of `.dat` files use the second command!

Answer (score 0):

Do you count this as one step?

```
for i in ../healthy_data/*; do 
   sed 's#\.[^.]*##'<<< "${i##*/}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't strip both a prefix and suffix in a single parameter expansion.

However, this can be accomplished in a single loop using parameter expansion operations only.  Just save the prefix stripped expansion to a variable and use expansion again to remove its suffix:

```
for file in ../healthy_data/*; do
    prefix_stripped="${file##*\/healthy_data\/}"
    echo "${prefix_stripped%.dat}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on `zsh`, one way to achieve this without the need for defining another variable is

```sh
for i in ../healthy_data/*; do echo "${${i#../healthy_data/}%.dat}"; done
```

This removes prefix and suffix in one step.

Answer (score -1):

In your specific example the prefix stems from the fact that the files are located in a different directory.  You can get rid of the prefix by `cd`ing in this case.

```
(cd ../healthy_data ; for i in *; do echo ${i%.dat}; done)
```

The `(`parens`)` invoke a sub shell process and your current shell stays where it is.  If you don't want a sub shell you can `cd` back easily:

```
cd ../healthy_data ; for i in *; do echo ${i%.dat}; done; cd -
```